# Проверка наличия и работоспособности Zend Framework

Tags: apache, php, zend-framework, linux

Здравствуйте! Так получилось, что я в разное время инсталлировал то части, то еще непонятные куски кода из сайта компании производителя. У меня есть некоторый список инсталлированных пакетов и инсталлированный апач.

Дайте какой-то код для проверки, работает ли у меня этот фреймворк.
И еще, я нашел на сайте зенда сервер, но он там только на 30 дней. Есть ли какие-то версии для домашнего использования типа для изучения этого фреймворка? Или может мне достаточно будет иметь апач на компе? И какую IDE посоветуете для разработки страниц?

Comment: сервер на сайте Zend платный только в одной из версий, через 30 дней с от него отваливается некоторый дополнительный функционал, но основа WAMP остается рабочей. Можно скачать сразу бесплатную "Comunity" версию сервера.
Zend Framework это набор php файлов организованных в библиотеку. Т.е. для того чтобы она у вас заработала, никаких танцев не нужно, скачайте библиотеку и сохраните в области видимости проекта, а еще лучше воссоздайте рекомендованную структуру и все заработает без танцев с бубном.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно установить связку Apache + PHP (+mod_reqrite on)+ MySQL что бы нормально работать. Или пойти более легким путем - поставить XAMPP. Скачать фреймворк, создать виртуальных хост, залить файлы фреймворка на виртуальных хост и работать.

Если хотите более комфортную работу с Zend Framework то можете установить NetBeans (PHP) последней версии. Там есть поддержка этого фреймворка.